# Xperia Play (R800a) stuck at Sony Ericcson logo on boot

Tags: boot, sony-ericsson-xperia-play

OK then: Recently, the Xperia Play's screen has been broke. I just put in the new flex cable and THAT seems to work... except now:

1. I can only start the phone on USB power, otherwise it freezes at the splash.
2. If it boots, the touch screen doesn't work. As I can't unlock it without a touchscreen, I couldn't test it.

I did tighten the digitizer cable after this, no dice.

[This link seems to describe my symptoms well.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2056309)

Comment: If there's no more suitable answer: A last ressort would be a factory reset, which you should be able to do from the recovery menu.

Comment: What recovery menu? There's no recovery on the phone (bootloader locked)

Comment: Even with a locked bootloader, there usually is a stock recovery. For other ways, you can also check at [hard-reset.com](http://www.hard-reset.com/sony-ericsson-xperia-play-hard-reset.html).

Comment: So appearantly, I can't install updates through PC Companion unless the phone is unlocked... wow. That's not going to help!

Comment: Sorry for that -- but not having a Sony Android-device myself, I must leave details to those knowing them...

Comment: Basically, I can't update the phone unless I unlock the screen... which I can't do because touch doesn't work. Trying to find some form of download mode doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: OK then, reflashed with the Update Tool, still nothing